# Psychic Marauder Archetype

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype, psychic-class

Archives of Nethys, had a archetype called Psychic Marauder

I am looking for the psychic marauder archetype.

It was on the archives of Nethys site, which is down, and now I'd like another site I can find it at please or a copy of it.

Archives of Nethys: Pathfinder RPG Database ... archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?...Psychic%20Psychic%20Marauder Psychic Marauder. Source Heroes of the Darklands pg. 22.

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the archetype in question is open content under the license and that this question is not asking for pirated material?

Comment: Archive seems to be working fine.

Comment: I've tried from my desk top phone and ipad.   Also used chrome and safari browser  i can't get in. keep getting an error page. how you all getting in?

Comment: Please don't double post questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[The Psychic Marauder psychic archetype can be found here on Archives of Nethys.](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Psychic%20Psychic%20Marauder)

The contents of the page are too long to meaningfully quote here.